# Google Maps Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined"
when trying to create a map
In the Head:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
```

.............

```
function init(){


            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.552965, 172.47315);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


        }
```

.............

```
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:600px;height: 600px;">
        </div>
        <ul class="navigation">
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the problem is this is missing the closing tag for `<script>` for the include of jquery.js:

```
 <script 
   type="text/javascript"
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"/>
 <script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true">
 </script>
```

`<script>` tags need to be closed with `</script>`, it should be:

```
 <script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js">     
 </script>
 <script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true">
 </script>
```

For more information see: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 7):

Both the answers above will solve this problem if used together. Property LatLng is undefined because `google` object is not yet available.

You always close your `<script>` tag period.

`google` object wont be available till DOM is loaded. So in you javascript you have to use the google map's `addDomListener()`. Kara's solution is right but it wont work in your case since function name is init and addDomListener has to wait for "load". You would need:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Another very easy solution for this is to add the callback to the script

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=init
```

callback will wait for the script to load and then trigger your `init` function to initialize and draw your map.

I put the solution on CodePen here http://codepen.io/redbirdisu/pen/BHivq

Answer (score 0):

When do you run your init function?
if init function runs before google.js loaded, you can get this error.

try call init function like this.

```
function init(){
      //...
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'init', Initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, all syntax was correct. Tried to fix by moving script files up/down of the HTML file but none of them was successful.

What I did was, removed the `&callback=init` from the URL and call that method inside the `$(document).ready(function () {})`. Now it works perfectly.